# Solving 2D maze, how to avoid runtime error for hidden test case?

Tags: python, recursion, runtime-error, solver, maze

There are two test cases with this problem, the first test case is shown below and the second is a hidden test case that I still can't access. The first test case works perfectly however the second test case is showing me a runtime error. I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Help Donkey find refuge in the swamp. Unfortunately for him, Shrek’s swamp is a bit of a MAZE, and we need to help him find his way to Shrek’s hut. Donkey can only move up, down, right, and left, and he can only travel on dirt and lily pads.

**Input Format**

The first line will contain a single integer n that indicates the number of data sets that follow. Each data set will start with two integers, r and c, denoting the number of rows and columns in the maze. The following r rows will contain c characters: o – represents a Lily Pad . – represents dirt. W – represents water, Donkey cannot walk on these T – represents a tree, Donkey cannot walk on these M – represents mud, Donkey cannot walk on these D – represents Donkey’s current location, or the starting point of the maze. S – represents Shrek’s hut, or the end point of the maze.

**Constraints**

None.

**Output Format**

The output should be “We Making Waffles!!”, if it is possible for Donkey to make it to Shrek’s swamp, and “Silence is a friend that never betrays”, is it is not possible.

**Sample Input 0**

```
2
5 5
D..T.
.WoWW
.WooW
MMM.T
MMM.S
5 5
DTT..
...MM
WWMMM
WWMMM
TSMMM
```

**Sample Output 0**

```
We Making Waffles!!
Silence is a friend that never betrays
```

This is my code

```
import collections
for i in range(int(input())):
  wall, clear, goal = 1, 0, 'S' 
  width,height=map(int,input().split())

  def bfs(maze, start):
    queue = collections.deque()
    queue.append(start)
    seen = set([start])
    while queue:
        path = queue.popleft()
        x, y = path
        if maze[y][x] == goal:
            return True
        for x2, y2 in ((x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)): 
            if ( 0 <= x2 < width and  
                0 <= y2 < height and 
                maze[y2][x2] != wall and 
                (x2, y2) not in seen): 
                queue.append( (x2, y2))
                seen.add((x2, y2))
    return False

  mat=[]
  for i in range(width):
    mat.append(list(str(input())))

  def change(lol):
    for index,item in enumerate(lol):
        if isinstance(item, list):
            change(item)
        if item=='.':
            lol[index] = 0
        elif item=='o':
            lol[index] = 0
        elif item=='W':
            lol[index]= 1
        elif item== 'M':
            lol[index]=1
        elif item== 'T':
          lol[index] =1
    return lol
  change(mat) 

  def find(matrix, item):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        try: 
            j = matrix[i].index(item)
            return (i, j)
        except ValueError:
            pass

  start=(find(mat,'D'))
  end=(find(mat,'S'))
  mat[start[0]][start[1]]= 0

  final=(bfs(mat,(start)))
  if final== True:
    print("We Making Waffles!!")
  else:
    print("Silence is a friend that never betrays")
```

Because of the hidden test case, I am not sure what caused the runtime error, especially with the first testcase running perfectly fine.

Comment: Interesting problem.  Can you share the source link?  Given that no one can see the *hidden* test case.

Comment: You need to write your own test cases to unittest basic functionality. For example, have you tried a test case that is not a perfect square?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the runtime error! Here is my solution to help other people:

```
import sys
 
def isSafe(mat, visited, x, y):
    return 0 <= x < len(mat) and 0 <= y < len(mat[0]) and \
           not (mat[x][y] == 0 or visited[x][y])
 
def findShortestPath(mat, visited, i, j, dest, min_dist=sys.maxsize, dist=0):
    if (i, j) == dest:
        return min(dist, min_dist)
    visited[i][j] = 1
    if isSafe(mat, visited, i + 1, j):
        min_dist = findShortestPath(mat, visited, i + 1, j, dest, min_dist, dist + 1)
    if isSafe(mat, visited, i, j + 1):
        min_dist = findShortestPath(mat, visited, i, j + 1, dest, min_dist, dist + 1)
    if isSafe(mat, visited, i - 1, j):
        min_dist = findShortestPath(mat, visited, i - 1, j, dest, min_dist, dist + 1)
    if isSafe(mat, visited, i, j - 1):
        min_dist = findShortestPath(mat, visited, i, j - 1, dest, min_dist, dist + 1)
    visited[i][j] = 0
    return min_dist
 
def findShortestPathLength(mat, src, dest):
    i, j = src
    x, y = dest
    if not mat or len(mat) == 0 or mat[i][j] == 0 or mat[x][y] == 0:
        return -1
    (M, N) = (len(mat), len(mat[0]))
    visited = [[False for _ in range(N)] for _ in range(M)]
 
    min_dist = findShortestPath(mat, visited, i, j, dest)
 
    if min_dist != sys.maxsize:
        return min_dist
    else:
        return -1
def change(lol):
  for index,item in enumerate(lol):
      if isinstance(item, list):
          change(item)
      if item=='.':
          lol[index] = 1
      elif item=='o':
          lol[index] = 1
      elif item=='W':
          lol[index]= 0
      elif item== 'M':
          lol[index]=0
      elif item== 'T':
          lol[index] =0
  return lol
  
def find(matrix, item):
  for i in range(len(matrix)):
      try: 
          j = matrix[i].index(item)
          return (i, j)
      except ValueError:
          pass
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
  for i in range(int(input())):
    nums= input().split()
    nums= list(map(int,nums))
    mat=[]
    for i in range(nums[0]):
      mat.append(list(str(input())))

    change(mat) 
    src=(find(mat,'D'))
    dest=(find(mat,'S'))
    mat[src[0]][src[1]]= 1
    mat[dest[0]][dest[1]]=1

    min_dist = findShortestPathLength(mat, src, dest)
    if min_dist != -1:
      print("We Making Waffles!!")
    else:
      print("Silence is a friend that never betrays")")
```

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/divas-advanced : The question is called "Swamp (Novce/Advanced Division)